# Stream a huge Excel file, creating it on the fly?

Tags: python, excel, streaming, openpyxl, bigdata

I'm writing a web application that might sometimes output dozens of thousands of rows (or even more) in an Excel file. openpyxl was chosen for Excel output preparation, but I'm not sure if I could read the data from the database and output it at the same time. Is there a way to do that? Here's an example of what I mean in CSV:

```
def csv_view(request, iterator, keys):
    """A view that streams a large CSV file."""

    class Echo(object):
        """An object that implements just the write method of the file-like
        interface.
        """
        def write(self, value):
            """Write the value by returning it,
               instead of storing in a buffer."""
            return value

    def get_iter():

        writer = csv.writer(Echo())
        yield writer.writerow(keys)
        for row in iterator:
            yield writer.writerow(row)

    response = StreamingHttpResponse(get_iter(), content_type="text/csv")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="output.csv"'
    return response
```

Comment: By database do you mean the csv file?

Comment: By database I mean "any iterator". I basically need an equivalent of this `csv_view` function that would generate XLS on the fly instead of CSV. @jmunsch

Comment: Might be able to create a `SpooledTemporaryFile` with a maxsize of what excel can handle and then stream the chunked excel files? Looks like `write_only` mode uses `NamedTemporaryFile` with an unlimited size? Not sure about the use case.

Comment: You could query the xlsx file using ado to a recordset and iterate that instead?

Comment: @MacroMan:  could you elaborate?

Comment: If you can work with the Excel workbook via COM - the range object has a `.CopyFromRecordSet()` method which would mean you don't have to use an iterator - just get your data from the database into a recordset and use that method to "dump" the data in one go.

Answer (score 3):

openpyxl already provides a `write-only` mode designed for streaming use. However, as all XSLX files are actually zip files and, as the zip format does not allow streaming, it is not possible to stream XLSX files while they are being written.

Comment: Thanks! And regular .xls?

Comment: I don't know but I doubt it. Can't do "huge" XLS files anyway: limited to 256 cols and 65,000 odd rows.